# How to concatenate columns with Laravel 4 Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table called `tenantdetails` which contains

```
Tenant_Id | First_Name | Last_Name | ........
```

and I want to retrieve `First_Name` and `Last Name` as one column via the concatenation function of MySQL. So I write in my `controller` as follows

```
$tenants = Tenant::orderBy('First_Name')->lists('CONCAT(`First_Name`," ",`Last_Name`)','Tenant_Id');
```

But results the following error:

> ```
>  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
>  in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>  version for the right syntax to use near '`," ",`First_Name`)`, 
>  `Id` from `tenantdetails` order by `F' at line 1 
>
>  (SQL: select `CONCAT(`First_Name`," ",`Last_Name`)`, `Id` 
>  from `tenantdetails` order by `First_Name` asc).
> ```

How can we avoid the backticks while calling a function of MySQL in Laravel Eloquent. I am interested only in Eloquent (not in fluent query). Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Thanks to @Andreyco for helping me. We can achieve this in a more elegant way using Laravel models, as below:

In our `model`:

```
public function getTenantFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['First_Name'] .' '. $this->attributes['Last_Name'];
}
```

and in our `controller`:

```
$tenants = Tenant::orderBy('First_Name')->get();
$tenants = $tenants->lists('TenantFullName', 'Tenant_Id');
```

Comment: This model solution is awesome. Is this in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: @Kyle Ridolfo. Thanks. Actually I forget the source for the solution. But I am sure it is not on the documentation until that day which I searched for the solution.

Comment: If anyone is still interested, documentation is here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators (this points to the latest Laravel version, you need to check out the version used in your project).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
Tenant::select('Tenant_Id', DB::raw('CONCAT(First_Name, " ", Last_Name) AS full_name'))
    ->orderBy('First_Name')
    ->lists('full_name', 'Tenant_Id');
```

Comment: Is any possibility to do this only with  eloquent orm

Comment: I am a beginner to laravel. I think it is combination of Fluent Query Builder with Eloquent. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is Eloquent. In Eloquent you can use everything from Fluent. But it's still Eloquent, no matter what. Why is this not sufficient for you?

Comment: Thanks, this is enough for me. I just asked for to know whether we can do it only by eloquent or not (because now I am under learning process). Thanks for the help..

Comment: In Laravel 5 you have to either `use DB;` or call it with a backslash: `\DB::raw...`

Comment: @manuthalasseril I went with the `selectRaw` method suggested by @michel-ayres, but put it in a query scope (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) for simple re-use... makes it look more "Eloquent" :)

Answer (score 9):

An easy way is to use `selectRaw`. It was implemented by Tailor in `Jan 30, 2014`

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2918)

```
Tenant::selectRaw('CONCAT(First_Name, " ", Last_Name) as TenantFullName, id')->orderBy('First_Name')->lists('TenantFullName', 'id'))
```

Answer (score 4):

lists() method used to select column from selected result. So first contact first name and last name and give this column with new alias name in select statement

```
 $tenants = Tenant::orderBy('First_Name')->select(DB::row('CONCAT(`First_Name`," ",`Last_Name`) as name'),'Tenant_Id')->lists('name', 'id');
```

then you can select this alias in lists() method

Comment: just a note on the typo DB::row should be DB::raw, you may want to edit your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the **DB::raw()** to concat those of field

```
Tenant::select(
          'Tenant_Id',
          DB::raw('CONCAT(First_Name,"-",Last_Name) as full_name')

        )
       ->orderBy('First_Name')
       ->lists('full_name', 'Tenant_Id');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Query Builder to do this
like:

```
DB::table('Tenant')
->selectRaw('CONCAT(First_Name, " - ", Last_Name) as fullName, id')
->get();
```

Hope be helpful :)