# Output Laravel SQL Column as a link?

Tags: sql, laravel, hyperlink

I have a Javascript table pulling data into it from a Laravel Json response, I have the column 'name' I wish to turn into a link when it is in the table? Is there anyway to do it like this:

```
"SELECT CONCAT('<a href=computer/?id=',id,'>',name,'</a>') as name,
```

I would rather use eloquent rather than straight SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate columns with Laravel 4 Eloquent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008487/how-to-concatenate-columns-with-laravel-4-eloquent)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22008586/2119863 oh look, an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't advise building up HTML as part of your SQL query. Say you want to use that JSON feed somewhere else that doesn't support HTML in the field or you want to append a class to link you've got to change your code.

However there is nothing to wrong with building the link and passing that through you could consider using the [Appending Values To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) functionality of eloquent model.

So you could do something like

```
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['link'];

    public function getLinkAttribute()
    {
        return route('routeName', ['id' => $this->id]);
    }

}
```

If you really must pass back an anchor tag then you could use the `link_to_route` method which is part of the [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#generating-urls) package.